# Get OpenGL histogram of masked texture

Tags: c++, opengl, image-processing, histogram, mask

I can get the histogram of an opengl texture using the `glGetHistogram()` function.

Similar to the [OpenCV histogram function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html), where a second OpenCV matrix can be given as a mask, I have an OpenGL Texture and a binary mask (either as alpha channel or as a separate texture), and I would like to get a histogram of all the pixels in the image that are *not* masked.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I assume performance is important here? The GL imaging functions are not GPU-side assuming they're even available. Histograms are much easier to implement with compute shaders, that was the first thing I ever did using compute shaders in fact.

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks. Compute shaders would be an option. Do you have some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glGetHistogram is [deprecated](https://www.opengl.org/registry/oldspecs//gl.spec) since OpenGL 3.1 anyway.

Using compute shaders or [occlusion queries](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/presentations/2005/GDC/OpenGL_Day/OpenGL_Image_Processing_Tricks.pdf) would be a better idea.